Не запускается файл python ни в консоли, ни в vsc
Когда запускаешь файл в vsc выдает лишь его путь, а когда через cmd, то консоль на мгновение появляется и исчезает. Я уже пробовал запустить с отладкой, но и это не помогает.
То есть вот что выдает vsc при попытке запустить код - PS C:\Users\user\Documents\app> & C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/user/Documents/app/main.py

Так а что в программе и что ожидаете увидеть? Дополните вопрос

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Можешь скинуть скриншоты/видео, как это багается?
